# Add item to Observable Array Knockout

Tags: javascript, arrays, mvvm, knockout.js

I have 3 Observable Arrays:

```
self.sets1 = ko.observableArray([
    ]);
self.sets2 = ko.observableArray([
    ]);
self.sets3 = ko.observableArray([
    ]);
```

I have a constructor to make new records.

```
function Record(name1){
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name1);
    this.editing = ko.observable(false);
    this.edit = function() { this.editing(true) }
    self.remove = function(){
        self.remove(this);
    }
```

}

I have a function that adds records to one of my observable arrays.
Like so:

```
this.addSet = function(){
        self.sets1.push(new Record($('input[id=weight1]').val()+' x '+$('input[id=reps1]').val()));
    };
```

And in my view I call it like this:

```
<button id="btn1" data-bind="click: addSet">Add set</button>
```

But this is only for observable array `sets1`.

What I want is to make this function universal, so it could add records to any array, for example depending of the `id` of the `button` which is clicked.
But how can I get the needed `id` and pass this value to my function?
Or maybe there's a better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Knockout event bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) (like click) are provided two parameters that you may find useful.

```
function(data, event)
```

Here, `data` is the knockout object associated with the element that raised the event. `event` is the event object which contains data about the event. `event.target` is a reference to the html element that raised the event.

So to find the ID of the button that was clicked, do something like this:

```
this.addSet = function(record, event){
    var id = $(event.target).attr('id');
    ...
};
```